# Why am I getting out of range error?

Tags: function, python-3.x, range

I'm building a function to extract all negatives from the list xs. Then I'm appending those negatives to a list negatives, and adding list negatives to list new_home, which may or may not already have values to it. The function was working before I added xs.pop(num). Why is it now out of range?

Here is the code:

```
def extract_negatives(xs,new_home=None):
    negatives=[]
    if new_home==None:
    for num in range(len(xs)):
        if xs[num] <0:
            negatives.append(xs[num])
                xs.pop(num)
            return negatives
         else:
             for num in range(len(xs)):
                if xs[num] <0:
                    new_home.append(xs[num])
                    xs.pop(num)

     return new_home.append(negatives)
```

Comment: As a new programmer, I really didn't know to "see it coming." Be kind.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, you are mutating list passed to the function and hence index is getting messed up.
If you must delete from passed list then one idea is to delete at the end of function just before you returned result. That way mutation wont affect indexing.

Also , I don't understand why you have if and else both looking for `xs<0` . I cleaned up your function and got it working.

**EDIT1 -Working Code**

```
def extract_negatives(xs,new_home):
    negatives=[]
    for num in range(len(xs)):
        if xs[num] <0:
            negatives.append(xs[num])

    new_home = new_home + negatives 
    for i in negatives:
        xs.remove(i)

    return new_home

new_home=[-9,-11,]
xs = [ 2 ,-3, 4, -5, 6, -7]

    new_home =  extract_negatives(xs,new_home)
    print new_home
```

**Output**

```
>>> 
[-9, -11, -3, -5, -7]
 >>> xs
[2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: So this still fails most of the test cases and I think it has something to do with what needs to be returned. I'm still confused. Here is the prompt: The first argument, xs, contains integers. We will be removing any negative 
integers we find in xs, and appending them to the second argument, new_home. A reference to the 
list that received negatives must be returned. When no second argument is given, a list of all the 
extracted negatives should be created and returned.

Comment: @ocean.1234, I've updated my response, see above. Basically now we are feeding new_home as a parameter in addition to xs and appending negatives to new_home during every run. Hope this helps.